# Change value from one column into another

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have got a table:

```
ID        | Description
--------------------
1.13.1-3  | .1 Hello
1.13.1-3  | .2 World
1.13.1-3  | .3 Text
4.54.1-4  | sthg (.1) Ble
4.54.1-4  | sthg (.2) Bla
4.54.1-4  | aaaa (.3) Qwer
4.54.1-4  | bbbb (.4) Tyuio
```

And would like to change ending of ID by taking value from second column to have result like:

```
ID       | Description
--------------------
1.13.1   | Hello
1.13.2   | World
1.13.3   | Text
4.54.1   | Ble
4.54.2   | Bla
4.54.3   | Qwer
4.54.4   | Tyuio
```

Is there any quick way to do it in postgresql?

Comment: I assume the third line should be `'0.3 Text'`.

Comment: `substring(Description from '.*\.(\d*)')` to extract number, `substring(Description from '.*\.\d*\s*(.*)')` to extract text after number and `substring(ID from '(\d*\.\d*)\.')` or `substring(ID from '(.*)\.\d*-\d*')` to extract needed part from ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to manipulate the strings into what you want:

```
update mytable set
ID = regexp_replace(ID, '\.[^.]*$', '') || substring(Description from '\.[0-9+]'),
Description = regexp_replace(Description, '.*\.[0-9]+\S* ', '')
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/16a52/2) showing this query working with your data.

Comment: sorry, i have edited data because i forgot about varius descriptions